# Understanding work in thermodynamic cycles and defining different systems

Tags: thermodynamics

I am confused about defining systems and calcuating work in a thermodynamic cycle, say a typical power cycle. Such a cycle might have a pump, boiler, turbine, and condenser.

Now the typical assumption is if we define a system as a boiler or as a condenser, we say that no work is done on those systems and the only relevant terms in an energy balance would be heat transfer and the enthalpies of the masses coming in and out. In this kind of scenario, would the efficiency of the cycle be defined as Wnet / Qin where Qin is the heat added to the boiler and work net is the difference between the work done by the turbine and the work added to the pump?

But if I look at the gas as a system rather than each individual component, I would want to assert that the gas in the boiler and condenser does work because of the change in its volume (dW = P dV). Am I correct to assume this? And if so, would the gas as a system on its own in the turbine do a different amount of work than the amount of work the turbine (if the turbine is the system) might produce in the same cycle?

And if so, would asking what the efficiency of the cycle yield a different answer when defining the system as the gas in the cycle versus each block of the cycle as a system?

EDIT: In the last part, would the net work we use for defining efficiency if the system is the gas alone the net work performed by the gas in all 4 blocks of the cycle (its two expansions and compressions)? Contrast this with my previous assumption where work net is the difference in work the turbine outputs minus the work input into the compressor/pump if the systems are each block.

Comment: Are you familiar with the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics, and its derivation from the closed system version of the first law?  If so, then you know that (1) the focus of the closed system version is on the working fluid (2) the focus of the open system version is the equipment through which the working fluid is flowing, (3) the open system version splits the work into shaft work and work to force fluid into or out of each piece of equipment, and (4) that the two versions give equivalent results.

Comment: By equivalent you mean the cycle's efficiency will be the same? And also the net work? And if so, how does the fluid technically do work if it's stuck inside a component like a turbine as its volume increases?

Comment: To your first question, yes.  To your second question, the work required to push fluid into and out of each component cancels with the work into and out of the adjacent components.  So the only work remaining is the shaft work in the compressor and pump, and the shaft work in the turbine.  These devices function by the gas doing work on (or receiving work from)  rotating shafts that have  attached blades.

Comment: I see the cancellation now when leaving one component and entering the next. But where does this "extra" work come from if everything might cancel itself when looking at the system as a fluid? Does it just always work out in the end that not all of it is cancelled out when looking at the turbine and compressor?

Comment: In applying the open system version of the first law to the turbine, the rotor and shaft are regarded as external to the open system (even though they are internal to the turbine shell), and only the gas space within the shell is regarded as  the open system.  So the moving turbine blades are part of the surroundings, and the gas does work on them as it flows through the turbine.  Thus, the gas space within the system has a moving boundary, even though the volume of the gas space is constant.  The turbine blades turn the rotor which delivers mechanical energy.  This is the "extra" work.

Comment: Alright the part about the flowing makes sense. But mathematically how does that "extra" work show up as mechanical energy when the blade spins if flow work should cancel as gas leaves and enters components?

Comment: In the compressor, the blades of the rotor are exerting forces on the flowing gas, and part of the gas displacement the they cause is forward.  The gas  pressure increases.  So the compressor does shaft work on the gas.  There is net heat added to the gas during the cycle.  So more shaft work is done by the gas on the rotor of the turbine than was absorbed by the gas in the compressor.  Only all the inlet and outlet work from the devices in the cycle cancel out.  The shaft portion of the work does not cancel out.

Comment: Got it. And lastly, in a compressor or turbine where the assumption is they are well insulated and no heat transfer occurs, does this means that if the system is the working fluid that no heat transfer occurs too? So the energy balance for the fluid would go to U2- U1 = 0 - W?

Comment: If you mean that $$-\dot{W}=\dot{m}(u_{out}-u_{in})$$where $$\dot{W}=\dot{W_s}+\dot{m}((Pv)_{out}-(Pv)_{in})$$then yes.

Comment: Ok makes sense. And to confirm I am correct to use u instead of h for enthalpy right because I am looking at the fluid as the system. If I looked at the component as a system it would be 0 = 0 - W + m(h1 - h2)? And if a component is well insulated where no heat flows in or out to the surroundings, can it be assumed that no heat flows into or out of the working fluid forcing Q = 0 for both systems?

Comment: Well, you are aware that $h=u+Pv$, so, in terms of shaft work, $$\dot{Q}-\dot{W_s}=\dot{m}(h_{out}-h_{in})$$while in terms of total work $$\dot{Q}-\dot{W}=\dot{m}(u_{out}-u_{in})$$ so, either way, you get the exact same result.  The difference is not whether you are looking at the fluid or the control volume, it is whether whether you are working in terms of shaft work or in terms of total work.  For systems like the one your are considering, shaft work is more convenient to work with, so it is the enthalpy which comes into play.

Comment: Thanks. And my last question is, if a component is assumed adiabatic like a turbine, does this necessarily mean the gas inside it as a system expands adiabatically too? Or is this assumption false and the gas can have heat transfer to the turbine but the turbine itself does not exchange heat with the surroundings, only doing work?

Comment: If the system is operating adiabatically and at steady state, there is no heat exchange between the gas and the turbine metal ( including both the shell and rotor).

Comment: Oh so it doesn't matter if I define the system as the working fluid or as the turbine? No heat transfer can occur in either system if I saw the turbine as a whole is operating adiabatically within its surroundings?

Comment: It does matter.  The gas is doing work on the turbine rotor and, in this continuous flow system, the turbine is not flowing,  Plus, if you wish to determine the work (assuming that the gas is deforming reversibly), you need to treat the gas as your system.

Comment: But by defining a turbine as adiabatic with its surroundings, this also means that no heat transfer occurs between the gas and the turbine if I say my gas is the system?

Comment: I don't understand.  Heat transfer is not the only consideration.  Work is also a consideration,.

Comment: Right I know that, but in the energy balance equation, would Q = 0 for both the turbine as a system and the gas as a system if the turbine is defined as operating adiabatically? Or would Q=0 only for the turbine as a system?

Comment: Yes.  There would be no heat transfer to both the turbine and the gas.  It seems to me this discussion is starting to go nowhere.  Might I suggest that your time would be better spent at this point solving some problems in order to solidify your understanding.  You'll get the gist of how this all works by doin that.

Comment: Alrighty, well thanks for sticking with me all the way.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_efficiency

Answer (score 0):

For each piece of equipment in the loop, the open system version of the first law of thermodynamics tells us that:
$$\dot{Q}-\dot{W_s}=\dot{m}(u_{out}-u_{in}+(Pv)_{out}-(Pv)_{in})$$where $\dot{m}$ is the mass flow rate, $\dot{Q}$ is the rate of heat addition to the piece of equipment, $\dot{W_s}$ is the rate of shaft work done by the piece of equipment on the surroundings, u is the internal energy per unit mass, P is pressure, and v is specific volume.  The rate of work done to push mass into and out of the piece of equipment is $\dot{m}((Pv)_{out}-(Pv)_{in})$.

Note that, for each individual piece of equipment in the loop, the right hand side of the equation is not necessarily zero.  Therefore, the change in internal energy between inlet and outlet plus the net work done required at the inlet and outlet to push material in and out of the equipment captures the combined effect of the heat added to the individual piece of equipment and the shaft work done by the equipment.  But, if we add up these heat balance equations for all the pieces of equipment in the closed loop (operating at steady state), we obtain:  $$\sum{\dot{Q}}-\sum{\dot{W_s}}=0$$
and $$\sum{\dot{m}(u_{out}-u_{in}+(Pv)_{out}-(Pv)_{in})}=0$$

The latter is a requirement that the system be operating in a cycle.